# How to check database field is true in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am trying to create a script in c# that checks to see if the user in the table is an admin. I have it set to a boolean value where true is admin and false is not. Ive created a command that selects all users from a table where they are admins. Im not sure how to then use this to implement in my id statement. How might I achieve this?

```
    public Boolean checkIfAdmin()
    {
        Connect database = new Connect();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From tbl_user WHERE user_isAdmin = true", database.getConnection());

        if (/*User is Admin*/)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

How might I get the if statement to return true if the user is an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to select **user_isAdmin** in your query where **user ID** (*your table column*) = **current user ID**. Then make an execute scalar to your sql command to extract your result into a boolean variable.
Example:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT user_isAdmin From tbl_user WHERE user_id = " + userID, database.getConnection());
bool isAdmin = (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();

if(isAdmin) { //Do what you want as admin }
else { //Do what you want if he's a user }
```

Comment: Please, don't show code that concatenates strings to build a query. Use Command Parameters (`[Command].Parameters.Add()`)

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, that's true, it's better to use Parameters than passing value in query (SQL INJECTION).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?